# android studio has hidden elements in activity

Tags: android-studio

|I just added new activity (chose settings template) when i created my app in my setting page there are some elements that aren't exist in my editor nor in xml code.

## Screenshots

**In App**

[image: one]

**In Editor**

[image: two]

## Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/settings">


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4sp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/appLang"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/applangtext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/applangtextstring" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_indo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                        android:text="@string/indoLang" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio_english"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                        android:text="@string/englishLang" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/learnLang"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/learnlangtext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/learnLangText" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/learn_radio_indo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButton2Clicked"
                        android:text="@string/indoLang" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/learn_radio_english"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="onRadioButton2Clicked"
                        android:text="@string/englishLang" />

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Check you `setContentView` method inside `onCreate` method in your corresponding java/kotlin file

Comment: @lkdhruw `setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);`

Comment: The code you have shown here is from the same file `settings_activity.xml`

Comment: yes i only have 1 settings page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

There was some extra lines in my settingsActivity file in `ocCreate()` function after removing them and rebuild my app UI issue was solved.

My current `onCreate()` function is like this now:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);

        // here was some lines regarding to Topbar
}
```

> Note: what was connection between topbar(toolbar) and UI issue
>   personally i don't know but my problem solved after removing that and
>   that's all matter :)